# Python grpc protobuf stubs generation issue: --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1

Tags: python, grpc, protocol-buffers

As the question says, I compiled grpc from source and also did `sudo pip install grpcio`, however, the `which grpc_python_plugin` doesn't return anything. This is a problem because the grpc python example for route_guide requires me to run `protoc -I . --python_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc='which grpc_python_plugin' ./route_guide.proto`
 in order to generate the python stubs. Since, `which grpc_python_plugin` doesn't return anything, I get the following error:

```
: program not found or is not executable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

If I shorten the command I'm trying to run to:`protoc -I . --python_out=. ./route_guide.proto`, it generates the route_guide_pb2.py file but without the Servicer and Stub classes, and server and stub methods. Ofc, these methods are necessary if one wants to use grpc for any purpose. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`; `make install` uses a prefix of `/usr/local` by default. Alternatively, after compilation `grpc_python_plugin` should be in `bins/opt/`.

Comment: So is there a way to use protoc executable? not python -m?

Answer (score 13):

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. my_proto.proto
```

Edited:

Apparently, there is open Issue on gRPC github site regarding this problem. `Protoc` seems to have a compatibility issue with `grpc_python_plugin`? I solved this problem by installing `grpc_tools`, then used `grpc_tools.protoc` instead of `protoc`.

```
$ pip install grpcio-tools
$ pip install googleapis-common-protos
```

Useful python tutorial: https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html

**See Protoc Issues [791 and 4961]:**

- https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/791
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4961

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The operative part of this answer which helped me is installing `googleapis-common-protos` which allowed me to use `grpc_tools.protoc`

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this error make sure you have `grpc_python_plugin` installed on your system. 
On python platforms `pip install grpcio` doesn't install platform specific plugins, so you have to install them separately by taking following steps

- a) `cd grpc` (grpc repository)
- b) `git submodule update --init`
- c) `make grpc_python_plugin`

This will build the `grpc` python plugin for you. Now, find out the location of `grpc_python_plugin` on your system, lets call it `binary_path`

If binary_path is under `$PATH` environment variable (`echo $PATH`), you are good to go. However, if it is not under $PATH variable, you have two options

Update `run_codegen.sh` to `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=binary_path`
or, copy the binary to one of the locations tracked by `$PATH` environment variable

Comment: Hi, How can i do the same for Java? Stubs are not generating for Java.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022, the GRPC repo has been reworked.

Answer (score 3):

the python's gRPC plugin for `protoc` is not installed by default

```
$ protoc -I=grpc/protos helloworld.proto --plugin=grpc_python_plugin --python_out=grpc/helloworld --grpc_python_out=grpc/helloworld
protoc-gen-grpc_pythong is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--grpc_python_out: protoc-gen-grpc_python: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

install `protoc-gen-grpclib_python` and `protoc-gen-python_grpc`

```
$ pip install grpclib protobuf
```

generate your python gRPC stubs (replace `--grpc_python_out` with `--grpclib_python_out`)

```
$ protoc -I=grpc/protos helloworld.proto --plugin=grpc_python_plugin --python_out=grpc/helloworld --grpclib_python_out=grpc/helloworld
```

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15675

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem (`which grpc_cpp_plugin` was empty). In my case the problem was that I didn't have installed `grpc` and I solved this for my OS X with `brew install grpc`.