# Issue while generating grpc Java stub using protoc v3

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java, protoc

I am using Protoc version 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.4  and issuing command

```
 protoc -I ./ --java_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/opt/jvision/grpc/oc/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.0.0-linux-x86_32.exe ./agent.proto
```

[Same issue for python described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713861/python-grpc-protobuf-stubs-generation-issue-grpc-out-protoc-gen-grpc-plugin?rq=1)

I am getting this error:

```
/opt/jvision/grpc/oc/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.0.0-linux-x86_32.exe: program not found or is not executable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

However if i skip stub part and just issue command

```
protoc  -I=./ --java_out=. ./agent.proto
```

It works perfectly fine. Wondering what i am missing.

Comment: FYI 1.0.0 is pretty old now, you might consider upgrading to 1.2.0

Comment: So "protoc gen grpc" 1.2.0 goes with Protoc 3.2 compiler or can work with protoc 3.0 compiler as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't enough reputation for comments, so this is questions to author:

1. Have you checked "/opt/jvision/grpc/oc/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.0.0-linux-x86_32.exe" path? Is it correct?
2. Does it have executable flag?
3. Is it compiled for linux?

Comment: Thanks. Point number two fix the issue.                                          
protoc -I ./ --java_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.0.0-linux-x86_64.exe ./agent.proto

Comment: i dont know why this answer doesnt have more upvotes. 2nd step resolved it for me. bless you @Radiv

Comment: Thanks! The 2nd item is easy to miss, I do appreciate your answer.